# PL/SQL procedure with cursor and rowtype

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, procedure, rowtype

I am working in a games data base. I want to create a procedure which shows the games created between two dates.
I am using a cursor and a rowtype like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure p_games(v_date1 games.date%type, v_date2 games.date%type)
AS

    v_games games%rowtype;
   
    CURSOR checkGames IS
    SELECT * INTO v_games
    FROM games
    WHERE date BETWEEN v_date1 AND v_date2;
        
BEGIN
    FOR register IN checkGames   LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(register.v_games);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

but when I run it the error is

> PLS-00302: the component 'V_GAMES' must be declared.

Should I declare it in any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly like that.

- you don't have to declare cursor variable as you're using a cursor `FOR` loop
- you don't select `INTO` while declaring a cursor; you would `FETCH` into if you used a different approach (see example below)

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table games
  2  (id     number,
  3   c_date date
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into games (id, c_date) values (1, date '2022-04-25');

1 row created.
```

Your procedure, slightly modified:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE procedure p_games(v_date1 games.c_date%type, v_date2 games.c_date%type)
  2  AS
  3      CURSOR checkGames IS
  4      SELECT *
  5      FROM games
  6      WHERE c_date BETWEEN v_date1 AND v_date2;
  7
  8  BEGIN
  9      FOR register IN checkGames LOOP
 10          dbms_output.put_line(register.id);
 11      END LOOP;
 12  END;
 13  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec p_games(date '2022-01-01', date '2022-12-31');
1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

A different approach; as you can notice, a cursor `FOR` loop is way simpler as Oracle does most of the *dirty* job for you (opening the cursor, fetching from it, taking care about exiting the loop, closing the cursor):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE procedure p_games(v_date1 games.c_date%type, v_date2 games.c_date%type)
  2  AS
  3      CURSOR checkGames IS
  4      SELECT *
  5      FROM games
  6      WHERE c_date BETWEEN v_date1 AND v_date2;
  7
  8      v_games checkGames%rowtype;
  9  BEGIN
 10    open checkGames;
 11    loop
 12      fetch checkGames into v_games;
 13      exit when checkGames%notfound;
 14
 15      dbms_output.put_line(v_games.id);
 16    END LOOP;
 17    close checkGames;
 18  END;
 19  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec p_games(date '2022-01-01', date '2022-12-31');
1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: You'd concatenate them into the same dbms_output.put_line call. For example: `dbms_output.put_line(register.id || ', '|| to_char(register.c_date, 'dd.mm.yyyy'));`

Comment: Thanks. But Can I use a for loop and show all data about the games, and not only the id? or to get it I must use "the long way"?

Comment: Didn't you see my previous comment (which answered the same question you posted and then deleted)?

Comment: I'm sorry I had not seen your previous comment.